# ASP.NET MVC Custom RoleProvider cannot retrieve roles from database for username

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roleprovider

i cant seem to find the right solution for the above issue. I keep getting `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

i followed this guide http://techbrij.com/custom-roleprovider-authorization-asp-net-mvc

The error message is from my custom roleprovider from the GetRolesForUser(string username) at line `var user = _VisitorService.GetVisitors().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);`

The VisitorService works in the Controller but not in the RoleProvider.

below are the code please advice as required. Thanks you in advance.

Custom RoleProvider

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TamilLeague.Service;

namespace TamilLeague.WebUI
{
    public class myRoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
    {
        private readonly IVisitorService _VisitorService;
        public myRoleProvider(IVisitorService visitorservice)
        {
            _VisitorService = visitorservice;
        }
        public myRoleProvider() { }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {            
            var user = _VisitorService.GetVisitors().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
            if (user == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                string role = user.Role.Title;
                string[] rol = { role };
                return rol;
            }
        }
}
```

My Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(UserLoginVM thisUser, string returnUrl)
        {
            var visitor = _VisitorService.GetVisitors().FirstOrDefault(v => v.Username.ToLower() == thisUser.Username.ToLower());

            if (visitor == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Username not found in system. Please register or change the username.");
            }
            if(!visitor.checkPassword(thisUser.HashedPassword))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Username or password is incorrect.");
            }

            if (visitor.IsFreezed == true)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Account is freezed. Contact the administrator please.");
            }

            if (visitor.IsConfirmed == false)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Username", "Account is not activated. Contact the administrator please or log into your email to activate your account.");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(thisUser.Username, true);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("GiveAccess", new { id = visitor.ID });
                }
            }
            return Content("Testing");
        }
```

GiveAccess method

```
public ActionResult GiveAccess(int ID)
        {
            var user = _VisitorService.GetVisitor(ID);
            String[] roles = Roles.Provider.GetRolesForUser(user.Username);

            if(roles.Contains("Administrator"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SysUser", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Member");
            }
            //RedirectToAction("Index", "Member");
        }
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login"/>
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TamilLeagueRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="TamilLeagueRoleProvider" type="TamilLeague.WebUI.myRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="false"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameterless constructor in myRoleProvider which does not instantiate the service. Are you sure the class isn't entering that constructor? If it is, then you'll get a null reference exception when you try to use the service.

Comment: Thats what i thought.. but when i remove the parameterless constructor i get the error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." :(

Comment: See Wins answer below. You need to instantiate the service in the parameterless constructor

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject dependencies to RoleProvider via constructor. In other words, **Provider Model** doesn't now allow parameterized constructor.

In order to solve it, you want to use [Service Locator Pattern](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/).

For example, in Autofac -

```
private IVisitorService VisitorService { get; set; }

public MyRoleProvider()
{
   var cpa = (IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
   var cp = cpa.ContainerProvider;

   VisitorService = cp.RequestLifetime.Resolve<IVisitorService>();
}
```

Comment: hi i implemented autofac now i get IContainerProviderAccessor could not be found. 'private IVisitorService VisitorService { get; set; }
        public myRoleProvider(IVisitorService visitorservice)
        {
            _VisitorService = visitorservice;
        }
        public myRoleProvider() 
        {
            
            var cpa = (IContainerProviderAccessor) HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
        }'

Comment: Could you try  `var visitorService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IVisitorService>();`?

Comment: when i enter the namespace Autofac.Integration.Web; it says that Web does not exist in the namespace Autofac.Integration

Comment: You want to download [Autofac.Mvc5 from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/). If you want more information, look at [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#implement-icontainerprovideraccessor-in-global-asax).

Comment: Autofac.MVC5 is already installed. Now i get `None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'TamilLeague.WebUI.Controllers.UserController` .heres a part of my bootstrapper which is run by global ` builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(VisitorService).Assembly)
             .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
             .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();`

Comment: You question becomes sidetracked, and becomes autofac issue. Please search in Stack Overflow regarding [Autofac](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+autofac+None+of+the+constructors+found).